# Objective c - Multiple scrollviews inside a scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

So, I got 2 Scrollviews inside a scrollview that fills the whole ViewController.

[image]

so the first SV is scrolling without a problem, the contentSize for the 2 sub SV is set.

unfortnatly I think it has to be something with Autolayout... Its on and if I turn it off, the 1. SV dont scroll but the sub SVs.

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You mean to say the inner scrollviews are not scrolling?. Did you pass the touches event to next responder?.

Comment: Yes correctly ! How do I pass it to next responder??

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding `hitTest:withEvent:` in a custom `ScrollView` subclass. The following code should make the inner UIScollView handle all the touches on it.

```
@interface MyCustomScrollView : UIScrollView
@end

@implementation MyCustomScrollView
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* handler = nil;
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                CGPoint subPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:view];
                handler = [view hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
                if (handler) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (nil == handler) {
            handler = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        }
    }
    return handler;
}
@end
```

Note: scrollable subareas inside of a scrollable area makes bad user experience. Consider resizing inner scroll views to fit their content.

Comment: Additional note on the implementation. According to the documentation you should check for `pointInside:withEvent:` on a subview before asking it for `hitTest:withEvent:`. But this is not true. The system always calls only `hitTest:withEvent:` on a view and it is up to the view to check if the touch points in it.

Comment: ty, ill try that out after work.. I was also thinking to outsource the inner scrollviews.. Ill think about that.. I will answer as soon as possible!!

Comment: I tryed that code now.. itdidnt worked out :/ I have set it first to the sub SVs and after it to the outer SV.. nothing :S Ill outsource the sub SVs. But if you gett another just tell

Answer (score 0):

Generally scrollview eats all the touch events. Hence the subviews of scrollview do not get touch events. To enable touch events in subviews you can pass the touch event to the next responder from scroll view.

You can do that by over riding touches method in an scrollview subclass. Detailed explanation with example can be found [here](http://www.herbert-siojo.com/2011/04/01/forwarding-touches-to-subviews-of-uiscrollview/).

Comment: I will check that as soon as I m home!

Comment: Im sorry but i dont really understand the example... its using a costum VC that propose i dont understand..